# How to create a hardcoded date parameter for use in a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssms

Example (not working like this):

```
SELECT * FROM User 
WHERE LastActivity > Date(1980,1,1)
```

Where Date should use the parameters year, month, day as integer numbers. To avoid troubles with locales, I explicitly do not want to use a string like "yyyy/mm/dd" or similar.

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on an MSSQL Database, if this matters.

Note: I am sure this is trivial, but I could not find the solution neither using google or SO.

Comment: Can you use a Unixtimestamp?

Comment: Yes.......................

Comment: While I don't know which programming/scripting language you're using to make that query, I'm pretty sure that it has some capabilities to convert a standard date to a unix timestamp. Or simply hardcode the timestamp itself.

Comment: In addition to other comments and answers, note that the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) describes in detail what formats are possible for `datetime` literals. In particular, note the section on ISO 8601, which uses the word "unambiguous".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> To avoid troubles with locales, I explicitly do not want to use a
>   string like "yyyy/mm/dd" or similar.

To avoid this, the best way is passing the date as language-neutral like `YYYYMMDD`. This way it will be language independent:

```
SELECT * FROM User 
WHERE LastActivity > '19800101';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ISO date format` which is `yyyymmdd`

```
SELECT * FROM User 
WHERE LastActivity > CONVERT(DATE, (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), @Year) + 
                                    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Month),2) + 
                                    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Date),2) ))
```

Comment: `@months` and `@date` should be filled with leading zeros in order to be converted correctly, one way is to use `RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 2) + CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)` instead of `CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @Month)` the same with `@date`.

Answer (score 0):

I have always found that most databases will accept 'dd-mmm-yyyy' as a date parameter and I use it almost everywhere. There are some who don't (E.g. MS/Access) but SQL/Server does. This format is widely accepted, though obviously you may need to make it language specific.

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE LastActivity > '11-Dec-2012';
```

Comment: How can it be locale independent when it contains an *English* abbreviation for the month name? Try this: `set language spanish; select cast('11-Dec-2012' as datetime);`. As I commented above, the documentation says that the ISO 8601 format is unambiguous; other formats may be interpreted differently. [ISO 8601 is even interpreted correctly if you've messed with `SET DATEFORMAT`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'Convert' function does what your looking for. To make the 20th of March 1980, do the following:

```
Convert(date, '1980-03-20')
```

Your exact query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM User 
WHERE LastActivity > Convert(date, '1980-01-01')
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and up, you can use the simpler DATEFROMPARTS function:

```
SELECT * FROM User 
WHERE LastActivity > DATEFROMPARTS(1980,01,01)
```